# Android Colors ressources from PCL data Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, colors

Do you know if it is possible to fulfil the color.xml from my const class Color in my PCL Project?

Otherwise I will have to duplicate my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <color name="StatusBar">#F0EBE8</color>
</resources>
```

If not, is it good practice to check in an Android load class that I have the same value from my PCL and my color.xml file

Thx

Comment: You can make a helper method that takes in your PCL string and converts the Hexadecimal string to an `Android.Color`. I believe this is close to the `Color.ParseColor()` method. Splat does something similar: https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat/blob/develop/src/Splat/Android/Color.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You **can't** fulfil your `color.xml` from your colours in `App.xaml.

But remember that you need to **minimise** the amount of code that you put in your **platform-specific projects**.

> In this way, **you should have just general styles** in your android project in order to match the branding(styles and colors) that you have defined in your `Xamarin.Forms App`,for example the **status bar background color** to match the Xamarin.Forms `NavigationPage BarBackgroundColor`.